# Spring Boot Feign requestParam containing an array

Tags: arrays, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I'm trying to query the https://transport.opendata.ch/ API. In this API, it is possible to filter the response to avoid a big payload (using `?fields[]=...`).

For example : http://transport.opendata.ch/v1/connections?from=Lausanne&to=Zurich&fields[]=connections/from&fields[]=connections/to

I'm using Spring Boot and Feign, here is my code :

```
@FeignClient(value = "transport", url = "${transport.url}")
public interface TransportClient {

    @RequestMapping(method = GET, value = "/connections", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    Connections getConnections(@RequestParam("from") String from, @RequestParam("to") String to, @RequestParam("fields[]") String[] fields);

    default Connections getConnections(String from, String to) {
        return getConnections(from, to, new String[] {"connections/from", "connections/to"});
    }
}
```

The trouble is the generated request :

http://transport.opendata.ch/v1/connections?from=Lausanne&to=Zurich&fields%5B%5D=connections%2Ffrom%2Cconnections%2Fto

As you can see, the url is encoded and the array is not correctly binded (using comma instead of several `fields` in the url).

Is there any way to achieve this? If it cannot be done with FeignClient (Spring), maybe with Feign it is possible ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your typical request looks like:

```
 /api?fields=1&fields=2&fields=3
```

or

```
 /api?fields=1,2,3
```

And the controller method is:

```
@RequestMapping(method = GET, value = "/api", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
Connections getConnections(@RequestParam("fields") List<String> fields)
```

Comment: The final solution is the following one: 
    @RequestMapping(method = GET, value = "/connections", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    Connections getConnections(@RequestParam("from") String from, @RequestParam("to") String to, @RequestParam("fields[]") List<String> fields);

    default Connections getConnections(String from, String to) {
        return getConnections(from, to, Arrays.asList("connections/from", "connections/to"));
    }

Answer (score 0):

I've just found a solution:

```
@FeignClient(value = "transport", url = "${transport.url}")
public interface TransportClient {

    @RequestMapping(method = GET, value = "/connections?fields[]=connections/from&fields[]=connections/to", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    Connections getConnections(@RequestParam("from") String from, @RequestParam("to") String to);
}
```

I'm lucky because my fields are static, so I could put them directly in the URI, but how to handle this properly in a generic way?